# 2 Questions: Where are published programs stored and how to use .Text.Replace({},{})

Tags: vb.net

Where are the published programs with ClickOnce/OneClick (Whatever they are called) stored?
I just want to try and confirm is it:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZWD5DD4E.M7Q\644LG9VN.E7R\<program name in some long format>
```

Then with the Replace I'm using the following code to fetch the %appdata% folder information then trying to replace the "\Roaming" with "\Local..."

```
Imports System.Environment

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Get the path to the Application Data folder
    Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

    ' Display the path
    Label1.Text = appData
    Label1.Text.Replace("\Roaming", "\Local\Apps\2.0\ZWD5DD4E.M7Q\644LG9VN.E7R\vize..tion_72ba619dd371d095_0001.0000_a1b4f773f6ea0524")
    Label1.Text = appData
  End Sub
End Class
```

But it doesn't seem to replace the "\Roaming"
So if anyone knows how to use could you please tell me? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you ask two loosely related questions together? Don't be afraid to use the site too much.

Comment: Okay :3 I just didn't wanna seem like I was spamming xD

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The path of a ClickOnce installation is of the form you describe, but the exact makeup of the path is determined by some arcane feature of the installer - you can't hard-code it as in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Replace is a **function** not a method.  It returns a NEW string with the value substituted:

```
Label1.Text = appData.Replace("\Roaming", "\Local\Apps\2.0\ZWD5DD4E.M7Q\644LG9VN.E7R\vize..tion_72ba619dd371d095_0001.0000_a1b4f773f6ea0524")
```